# Testing QAbstractListModels

Tags: qt, unit-testing, testing, qt4, model-view

I want to test some QAbstractListModels I already implemented, is it better to use ModelTest from Qt labs or make my own unit test using QTestLib. Also can someone point me what actually ModelTest do and how to use it or a good tutorial on it other than this [one](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Model_Test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do both. ModelTest will only check that your model fulfils the basic expectations of the ModelView framework. You still need to write your own unit test cases to verify that your model operates specifically in the manner that you expect.

There are many models that may pass the ModelTest test, but you still felt the need to write your own. Obviously, there are special things about your model, or you wouldn't have bothered to write a new one. So, test those things!

Answer (score 1):

ModelTest simply listens to the signals that your model sends out. After every signal it verifies, as much as it can, that what the signal implies has actually happened within the model.

There's no tutorial needed, because it's trivial to use, just like the article you linked to shows.

Simply instantiate a ModelTest for your model. It can be even the model's child, so will exist as long as the model does. The helper function below illustrates that it is, in fact, trivial.

```
void instrument(QAbstractItemModel * model)
{
  new ModelTest(model, model);
}
```